# How to show a hidden div if hash matches its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a bunch of hidden `<div>`’s. I want to be able to link directly to any of them and have them show if the hashtag matches the `id`. I already have

```
var thisHash = window.location.hash;
if(window.location.hash) {
    $(thisHash).show();
}
```

I need to make sure **every** other `<div>` is hidden though. I can add a class if the hash matches the `<div>` but I’m not sure how to go about checking to see if the `id` of the `<div>`'s `id` matches the `.hash`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget) for it:

```
div { display: none; }
div:target { display: block; }
```

If you really want JavaScript:

```
$('div').hide().filter(location.hash).show(;
```

Comment: CSS is strongly preferable since browser will hide div as soon as see it in layout, while js script will probably run on body.onload.

Comment: Thanks so much Tommi but the page also has tabs at the top so I think I may have to go with the javascript.

Comment: You can easily restrict the selector so not every div is targeted but only divs with a certain class for example.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    $(window.location.hash).show();
}
```